# how does debounce without using rxjava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

I want to do a thing similar to [Debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) in Rxjava, but I don't use rxjava as well as using the other librarys. Everyone can suggest for me some ways of doing this.

Comment: Have you considered using Kotlin Coroutines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a function with `handler.postDelay()` and `runnable`, something like this:

```
private fun debounce(yourParams: Any, delayMillis: Long) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
        runnable = Runnable {
            // Your code here.
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayMillis)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen an implementation where you create a static variable and set it to true when clicked and then to false when done, because it is static, it disables all the views that use this type of `onClick` listener.

However, part of the debouncing in RxJava is time related, so i guess you could also add a timer.